# Remove border from component

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I want to create a search field with a combobox as prefix component so that the user can specify the entity type that he wants to search for.

To make it look nice, I want to remove the border from the combobox (and maybe from the textfield as well).

I thought that this code might do it, but unfortunately not. Result looks as shown below.

```
ComboBox<InformationType> informationTypes = new ComboBox<>();
informationTypes.setItems(InformationType.values());
informationTypes.addClassName(LumoUtility.Border.NONE);
```

[image]

Edit: The combobox informationTypes does not seem to be the element that owns the border. The border belongs to the div with the class vaadin-combo-box-container. And this element can not be styled according to https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/upgrading/essential-steps. So I guess the must be another way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the border that you'd like to remove is on a subcomponent within the **shadow-dom** of the `vaadin-combo-box`, you cannot edit that css via the java instance of `ComboBox<InformationType> informationTypes`.
However there is another way. You can read more details [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/styling-components)

step 1: create a .css file where you declare no border for `vaadin-combo-box-container`. Make sure this css only applies to subcontainers of comboboxes that have the class `addlater` so all your other comboboxes in your view stay unaffected by this.

```
/* borderless-combobox-container.css */

:host(.addlater) vaadin-combo-box-container {
    border: none;
}
```

step 2: include this css in your view. I use `@CssImport` for this in Vaadin 14, however the above-linked docs mention **this may have changed for vaadin 24** while still being supported. You may want to read more into that.

```
// this annotation can be on your routed view, or main/base view, 
// or if you have your own component class for your custom search field, you could add it there
@CssImport(value = "./styles/components/borderless-combobox-container.css", themeFor = "vaadin-combo-box")
public class MyView extends VerticalLayout {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kscherrer, that seems to be the way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know very much about VAADIN but I suspect that the line

```
informationTypes.addClassName(LumoUtility.Border.NONE);
```

is not correct.

You should use a CSS classname to add to the object, like so:

```
informationTypes.addClassName("borderless");
```

and the CSS for this should be like so:

```
.borderless {
  border-width: 0;
}
```

If you also want to remove the outline (when a user selects the search box) you can change the CSS to:

```
.borderless {
  border-width: 0;
  outline-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi JPA, thanks for your answer. I tried to add the class to the component. Then I found out that the parent element does not have a border but a div beneath this element. Hope my edit and the attached picture makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a solution. Create a css file with this content:

> vaadin-combo-box::part(input-field) {     border: 0;  outline-width: 0; }
>
> vaadin-text-field::part(input-field) {    border: 0;  outline-width: 0;
> }

... and import the css file in your java class:

> @CssImport("./styles/search.css")

OR use this css:

> :host([theme~="search-theme"]) [part="input-field"] {     border: 0;
> outline-width: 0; }

... import the css as shown above and attach the theme to each component that should use it:

> myinput.addThemeName("search-theme");